# Is it possible to create a thread without sharing memory space?

Tags: linux, thread, clone

The  http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html write

> Since Linux 2.5.35, flags must also include CLONE_SIGHAND if CLONE_THREAD is specified (and note that, since Linux 2.6.0-test6, CLONE_SIGHAND also requires CLONE_VM to be  included).

So it seems that on modern Linux, threads are forced to share signal handlers and memory space, is it true? Is there any way to create a new thread(the same `tgid` as the calling thread) without sharing memory space, maybe like by not using the `clone()`?

I also want to know, enforced by kernel, what are shared between threads in one process.

Comment: Isn't that a distinguishing factor between a thread and a process?  Shared process resources?  If you want a unique memory space then `fork()` to create a new process...

Comment: @Stephen I'm just talking about Linux kernel, for kernel,  it's only about tid and tgid. And I remember some old document said two threads can unshare the memory space from the kernel view, it now seems to be too old now.

Comment: You're talking about the `clone(2)` syscall, which can be used to create new "processes" which share various resources.  eg `clone()` with `CLONE_VM` will share memory space; without it each process has a unique memory space.    Similarly `CLONE_SIGHAND` will share signal handlers.   These are all ways that user level threads can be handled.  If you want to share handlers then you need to share memory.  If you don't want to share handlers then you don't need to share memory.